# ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit Combobox need to press enter twice to postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, combobox, autocomplete

im using a ComboBox for a feature in my application, and i have AutoCompleteMode="Suggest".

However, after i type the in the textbox for a search, and press Enter, nothing happens, i need to press Enter again to postback and show some results. Its kinda annoying and not intuitive to press Enter twice.

Its really weird, because when i go for debug mode i just need to press once...

Anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first Enter must be accepting the suggestion in the combo box, and the second Enter is pressing the Submit button on the page, possibly?

That's exactly what is happening on the sample page for the control, here: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didnt realised this is the default behavior... I will accept your answer and make a new question about how to avoid it behavior.